# Python adding an argument/attribute do derived class' constructor

Tags: python, class

I have a class `Record` :

```
class Record(object):
    def __init__(self, id=None, url=None, time= None, user=None, input_dict=None):
        if input_dict:
            self.from_dict(input_dict)
        else:
            self.id = id
            self.url = url
            self.time = time
            self.user = user

    def from_dict_internal(self, input_dict):
        #creates a record using data from a dictionary
        self.id = input_dict.get('id')
        self.url = input_dict.get('url')
        self.time = input_dict.get('time')
        self.user = input_dict.get('user')

    def from_dict(self, input_dict):
        return self.from_dict_internal()
```

I want to make a derived class `Page` with 1 extra attribute - referrer. I am not sure how to go about it as I have tried this:

```
class Page(Record):
    def __init__(self):
        Record.__init__(self)
        self.referrer = referrer

    def from_dict(self, input_dict):
        self.from_dict_internal()
        self.referrer = input_dict.get('referrer')
```

However Pycharm keeps underlining the `referrer` in the constructor of page with a reason of unresolved reference

Comment: You miss "referrer" variable in constructor arguments for Page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an error because `referrer` is not declared anywhere or passed into the **init** method.  Also you should pass in the same data that your `Record()` class uses.

```
    def __init__(self, id=None, url=None, time= None, user=None, input_dict=None, referrer=None):
        Record.__init__(self, id, url, time, user, input_dict)
        self.referrer = referrer
    ....
```